# Show that for $n \in \Bbb R, n> 0$, that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {x^n} {e^x} = 0$

Tags: analysis

I wish to show that for $n \in \Bbb R, n> 0$, that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {x^n} {e^x} = 0$ by definition.

Take $\epsilon > 0$, then I should find an $N \in \Bbb N$, where $ \frac {x^n} {e^x} < \epsilon$ for $x > N$.

So $x^n < e^x \epsilon$, and $n ln x < ln (e^x \epsilon)$

then $x > n ln x - ln(\epsilon)$

Is this on track?

Comment: You may want to use the fact that, for every nonnegative integer $k$ and every nonnegative $x$, $$e^x=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{x^\ell}{\ell!}>\frac{x^k}{k!}$$ and choose $k$ carefully.

Comment: *every positive $x$.

Comment: @Did it seems if I define the ratio as a function of $x$ I can use l'Hopital's rule (differentitating ceiling n+1 times) but I can't seem to progress otherwise. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Did also I changed my post as I thought more, let me know :)

Comment: In the end, this depends on the results you consider as known. For example, if you know the expansion of the exponential, the method in my comment is direct. If you know that $e^x\gg x$ in the sense that $e^x/x\to\infty$ when $x\to\infty$ then use $$e^x=\left(e^{x/n}\right)^n\gg\left(x/n\right)^n$$ If you know that $x\gg\ln x$, use the method in your post and conclude with $$\frac{x}{\ln x}\to\infty\qquad\frac1{\ln x}\to0$$ And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}=0$ we show that $\forall\varepsilon>0~\exists M>0:\left|\frac{x^n}{e^x}\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>M$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\in\Bbb Z_{> 0}$. Using the power series for $e^{x}$, when $x>0$ we have
$$e^x=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}>\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\implies e^{-x}<\frac{(n+1)!}{x^{n+1}}$$
So when $x>\frac{(n+1)!}{\varepsilon}$, we have $$x^ne^{-x}< x^n\frac{(n+1)!}{x^{n+1}}< (n+1)!\frac{\varepsilon}{(n+1)!}$$
This can be generalized to arbitrary $n\in\Bbb R_{>0}$ by using the fact that, for $x>1$, we have $x^{n}<x^{N}$ where $N$ is an integer larger than $n$.

Comment: A crushing proof for sure. Can you address my comments ? I will give the upvote and accept regardless.

Comment: I'm unsure how you would obtain a sufficient $N$ in your argument from $x>n\ln x-\ln\varepsilon$ as the right hand side depends on $x$. Also, your comment about using L'Hopital's makes sense for integer $n$, however this would not really be a proof via the definition of a limit.